# Game and blitted images are no transparent

Tags: image, pygame, transparency, blit

I have a problem with no transparent png images in my pygame game.

I load png images and blit them to the screen. I have a dark background of game screen and white background of images. Although, the images blitted are visible with white background. I would expect images to be transparent however I can not achieve it.

I can not find an accurate information in internet with a solution to my problem.

Is there any chance somebody could point me into the right direction and review my game ? How to achieve transparency of images ?

Link to the python code and images:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ng99rqg4ur76msp/game.7z?dl=0

Pictures which shows my problem:
[image: Picture1]

Game background color: black. Image backgroud color: white. How to get the image background transparent so it is not visible regardless the game background color ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your question but if your image has a transparent background you just use

image = pygame.image.load("image.png").convert_alpha()

If it has a white background you probably want to set the colorkey like

image = pygame.image.load("image.png").convert()

image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

Comment: In both instances if I have a black screen background the images a loaded with a white background visible. It does not help if I either use convert_alpha() or set_colorkey((255,255,255)). Please refer to this link to see what is the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftz90nbgwaqa87w/problem.png?dl=0

Comment: I have tried: image = pygame.image.load("image.png").convert() instead of convert_alpha(). I did image.set_colorkey((255,255,255)) and it works. Keltusamor you have pointed me into the right direction so your answer helped me. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah forgot to mention this. If you want to set a colorkey you have to just convert() the surface